# Bootstrap pull-right only working at small width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I'm using Bootstrap to get some text and a button to appear on the same line on opposite sides of the screen. I'm using pull-right to bring the button to the right side of the screen, but it only works when the screen width is narrow. If I make it wider, the button moves next to the text. [Here's a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fw1hdaq7/2/) and the relevant code:

```
<body>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>Some Text</label>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Some Button</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div><p>The button only appears on the right side of the window when the width is fairly narrow, even though it has the Bootstrap 'pull-right' class.</p></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to get the button to the right at all widths? Apologies, I'm not great with Bootstrap and CSS, so I'm sure this is an easy thing that I'm missing. Also, for what it's worth, this is for an Electron app, so it only needs to work in Chrome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it's wrapped in a `form group` div, which is only the full width on smaller viewports. You could get rid of the `form group` and just make the div `width:100%` in css.